# Apple Push Notification Not Arriving on Test Device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, push-notification

I've followed [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW5).

Inside my application I successfully register for notifications (alerts, badges and sounds) and send the device token to my server (it's a 32 byte string, which I encode hexadecimally for transport and storage). This all works.

As stated in the docs, my provisioning profile contains 'aps-environment' set to 'development'. I have generated a PEM file from *both* the certificate and the key associated with this certificate.

I'm using Grocer (on [Github](https://github.com/grocer/grocer)) to send the notification from my server. Apple happily accepts the notification, but it never arrives on the device. I've tried numerous times in the past 12 hours, making sure the app is not running in the foreground. I'm using **gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com** as the endpoint.

I'm at a loss. What should I look at? Apple's own [Troubleshooting Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html)  didn't help me.

Some people have mentioned generating an Ad-Hoc provisioning profile (though Apple doesn't state this is needed). I tried it anyway, but the profile then say "production" under aps-environment and I cannot install my application on my device.

EDIT | I can only assume I have the PEM certificate set up incorrectly... I say this because grocer still appears to 'send' the notification even if I use some completely random certificate. Not sure how to debug any errors.

Comment: Wait, do I need to generate a production certificate even if I'm just using the sandbox? I've put the development certificate on my testing server.

Comment: no you dont need one. only when you make a release build

Comment: you can send a notification with a php script from your local machine, there you will get an error if your pem file is not correct.

Comment: I just tried it with the code in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277127/apple-push-notification-with-php-script and it claims to have sent. Is it usually this hard? :P

Comment: Then again, even if I use the wrong passphrase with that PHP script (or with grocer) it still claims to have sent.

Comment: Ermm, god knows what I've done, but my device token has a lot of FFFFFFFF in huge sections of it after I encode it. When I look at the log output of the original NSData only the first few bytes the last few bytes are the same. In short, it appears I am using a dud device token!

Comment: Indeed. It's working now. Complete and utter facepalm on my part! That was a fun half a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this was just me hex-encoding the device token incorrectly on the client side. I was effectively do this:

```
char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * 2 * numBytes);

while (numBytes--)
  sprintf(buf+=2, "%02x", *(bytes++));
```

The problem was that `bytes` was a `char*`, when it should have been a `unsigned char*`, so the data was getting corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

you need the sandbox gateway when you use the developer profile:

```
gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com
```

if this still dont work, try reboot the device! this often helps!

dont forget to change the link when your app is released!

Comment: This is what I'm using (stated in the question, but easy to miss ;)). I'll try rebooting (3 times :P).

Comment: you are using gateway.push.apple.com not gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com (.sandbox.) :o)

Comment: Oops, that's a typo in the question, sorry, my bad!

Comment: Rebooting doesn't appear to have helped. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: is your app configured for push-notification on "iOS Dev Center"  developer.apple.com? and did you select the push profile for your app

Comment: Yeah, the Push Notification heading indicates it's Active. What do you mean by "did you select the push profile for your app"? I have the provisioning profile for that app ID, yes. I think if I didn't have that part working then I wouldn't even be able to register the device and get a device token.

Comment: yes you are right, if you get a token, so that part should be ok.